# How to use more memory to run a PostgreSQL server in a Singularity Container on an HPC cluster

Tags: postgresql, hpc, singularity-container

I am running PostgreSQL 13.4 on Singularity 3.6.4 on a well resources HPC cluster as a data warehouse for 1.5 TB of data utilized by me team for research projects. The HPC cluster utilizes LSF for job scheduling. At present, I am running the server container with 4 cores and 30 GB of available memory.

The LSF summary for the job running the server shows a MEMLIMIT of 29.7 GB, but MAX MEM usage of less than 500 Mbytes.

Ultimately, I am trying to increase query speed, however I believe that increasing memory utilization will ultimately improve overall performance.

Current non-default postgres.conf settings are below:

```
max_connections = 30
shared_buffers = 7680MB
effective_cache_size = 23040MB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2
work_mem = 64MB
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 16GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2
```

Singularity image build from docker://postgres

Comment: Why do you think it would be faster with more memory?  Based on the summary, it sounds like it has not even attempted to use 1/10 of the memory already available to it.  Maybe the jobs you have tried to run to date are silly jobs that don't do anything interesting.  Can you describe them?  Does LSF summary count cache usage as memory usage, or does it consider memory unless it was mapped into a processes address space?

Comment: Not sure what qualifies as a "silly job" in your mind. So far, I've been running select queries on 25 - 200 GB tables, filtering using multiple where clauses, joining data from at least 2 and up to 5 other tables. 

Was the question about memory rhetorical? in my understanding there are 3 ways to increase speed; memory, processors and storage drives. Since less than 1/10 of the memory is being used for large data queries, that seemed a logical first step.

Comment: Can you look at pg_buffercache to see if that at least is full? Or use pg_prewarm to force data into it? Maybe LSF reporting of shared memory is wonky.  Postgresql makes heavy use of file system cache, and some tools report that cache (or people interpret the report of it) as 'unused' even though it might be the best use of that RAM.

Comment: In my understanding, Postgres makes use of OS disk cache and usually this is not counted as "used memory" but as a part of `buff/cache` (see `free` command). See https://madusudanan.com/blog/understanding-postgres-caching-in-depth/#OSCaching

Comment: What does `MAX MEM usage` *mean* ? [probably RSS]